# Is logback logging storage with AsyncAppender guaranteed to be chronological?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

Suppose that I log two events using `logger.info`, where `logger` is declared as `private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.class);`, and the two events are less than 1 millisecond apart.

I am wondering if the latter event (i.e. the one that is logger later) will always come after the former event in the stored `RollingFileAppender`? I am using `ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy` with `AsyncAppender`.

Comment: Which one do you consider _latter_ and which do you consider _former_? How can you tell?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The latter one is the one that is logger later in physical time. The code guarantees the chronological ordering. I am wondering if the stored logs must reflect this physical reality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AsyncAppender` is implemented with a `BlockingQueue`. The `Logger` will add a logging event to the queue and a single worker `Thread` will take from the queue and handle logging.

If your code guarantees the order of these chronologically (through locking or some other mechanism), then they are guaranteed to be ordered in the logs as well.

Comment: If you take a loot at the logback Logger implementation itself, there is no guarantee of ordering there.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/0.9.17/ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger.java#Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus%28java.lang.String%2Corg.slf4j.Marker%2Cch.qos.logback.classic.Level%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.Throwable%29

When a logger is shared between multiple threads, there is no guarantee that the logging event will get created in the same order as the calls to the logger.info() method

Comment: @kopytko That's why I stated _if the code guarantees it_. Assuming the logging code is within a critical section that's locked over, the log event is guaranteed to be put in the queue in sequential order. And since there is a single thread taking from the queue, it will also get it and log it in order.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple threads writing using same logger instance, you have no guarantee of ordering.

Take a look at the [logback Logger implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/0.9.17/ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger.java#Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus%28java.lang.String%2Corg.slf4j.Marker%2Cch.qos.logback.classic.Level%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cjava.lang.Throwable%29)

There is no synchronisation inside this method. It's possible that thread1 calls logger.info("1"), a moment later thread2 calls logger.info("2"), but the appender will receive the "2" before the "1".

If you need a ordering guarantee, you have to synchronise the calls to logger.info() yourself.